# How to put all Array values in $_GET[]

Tags: php, css

I want to apply a CSS class to some current page links on the HTML page using the `$_GET` global variable.

Example:

```
function active_links(){
  $active_links = array("home","html","css","jquery","php","sql","psd");
  if(isset($_GET[$active_links[0]])){       
     ?> class="active"<?php
  };
}
```

```
css: .active {
background-color: #00AFF0;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: block;
}
```

html: am calling the function in the anchor opening tag

```
<li><a <?php active_links();?> href="#">HTML HOME</a></li>
```

The above actually works fine, but I want to use all the values of the array so that if either any of the values is set, then PHP can go ahead and apply the CSS class to the element in which I called the `active_links(`) function.

How can I do that?

Comment: Uh, have you taken a look in the preview? Please learn to format the code properly.

Comment: sorry..I think its because i copied from Dreamweaver and paste it here...better formatting next time.@nicael

Comment: try `<li><a <?php echo active_links();?> href="#">HTML HOME</a></li>`

Comment: why on Mars would you want to do what you are doing? there are better ways

Comment: hahaha @PlatinumIndustries

Comment: okay...what is your method? @PlatinumIndustries

Comment: @urfusion...thanks for your answer but the echo function will only echo the index active_links[0] which is "home" in the array. it works the same as mine

Comment: i'm pretty sure you can use javascript, or even pure css to accomplish what you are trying to do. Using php to apply a class is bad for your health

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check to see if any of the keys in `$_GET` intersect with `$active_links`:

```
$active_links = array("home","html","css","jquery","php","sql","psd");

if(array_intersect($active_links, array_keys($_GET))){       
    ?> class="active"<?php
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over you get query string, but: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b9fa5daf97348173617a3eb688aad013fa50e4b

Comment: Possibly, not sure when you tried it.  I edited it a couple of times.

Comment: wow...that was great!...Thank you and may God increase you and multiply you.